# FTPS - LFTP problem

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, lftp, ftps

We have some trouble in my company with ftps access with a provider.

Here is our configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- LFTP | Version 4.6.3a

---

- Our_cert.crt
- our_key.key
- provider.crt
- AuthorityRoot.crt
- AuthorityRootCa.crt

Certificate authority = GlobalSign

```
#/home/USER/.lftp/conf
set cmd:time-style "%Y%m%d%H%M"
set ftp:ssl-protect-list false
set net:timeout 30
set net:max-retries 1
set ftp:ssl-allow true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data false
set ssl:ca-file   AuthorityRoot.crt / AuthorityRootCa.crt (both file in one )  # i dont even know if this is correct
set ssl:cert-file our_cert.crt
set ssl:key-file  ourkey.key
set xfer:clobber on
set ssl:verify-certificate false
```

Our command:

```sh
lftp   -e "debug 9; source /home/USER/.lftp/conf ;ls ;quit"   -u username,pwd ftp://provider.com  -p PORT
```

But when we try to reach our provider, we have an error:

```
**** SSL_connect: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Our provider can see when we try to reach them, they can validate our cert but we cant validate their cert.
Everything is ok on their side.

---

Btw:
Everything worked fine before yesterday when their certs was expired and they also switch CA. We just replace authorityRootCa.crt (the file with everything inside in the field ssl:ca-file) with the new one

---

Can someone tell me where should we put our certs or what's wrong here? 
Should we add provider.crt in our file ourcert.crt?

Comment: The problem is that ssl3 has been obsoleted and it is not supported anymore, I think.

Comment: you should be able to debug this with `openssl s_client -starttls ftp -CAfile AuthorityRootCa.crt -cert our_cert.crt -key ourkey.key -servername provider.com -connect provider.com:PORT`. if PORT is 990 instead of 21 then `-starttls ftp` should be removed. the CAfile should be the CA bundle

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think the error was defined first for sslv3, I don't think this message means the protocol is sslv3. random example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/da2861eefdcb86178c697d0fc39b458f3a4ec900/socket/ssl_client_socket_impl.cc#1772

Comment: oh I missed the provider.crt part. Yes won't hurt to try to bundle it to Our_cert for the debug command above. Also, be sure to have all cert data in PEM format (not DER etc.) for that command.